# Having doubts in the probability.

Tags: probability

The problem that I have questions is as below:

The three most popular options on a certain type of new car are a built-in GPS (A), a sunroof (B), and an automatic transmission (C). If 40% of all purchasers request A, 55% request B, 70% request C, 63% request A or B, 77% request A or C, 80% request B or C, and 85% request A or B or C, determine the probabilities of the following events. [Hint: “Aor B” is the event that at least one of the two options is requested; try drawing a Venn diagram and labeling all regions.]

a.The next purchaser will request at least one of the three options.

b.The next purchaser will select none of the three options.

c. The next purchaser will request only an automatic transmission and not either of the other two options.

d. The next purchaser will select exactly one of these three options.

I got my Venn diagram as in the picture:

[image: Venn diagram]

I got some doubts in questions "c" and "d".

For question "c", from diagram I think $P(C\cap(\overline {A\cup B})) = P(A\cup B\cup C)-P(A\cup B) = 0.85-0.63=0.22$

For question "d", by using similar methods from "c" I think $P = 3P(A\cup B\cup C)-P(A\cup B) -P(A\cup C)-P(B\cup C)= 3×0.85-0.63-0.77-0.8=0.35$

As in my solutions, I haven't used $P(A); P(B); P(C)$. Is there something I misinterpreted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use *all* the information given to answer a question.

Sometimes extra information is provided as a distraction.

You only need find the information required among what is given.  (The gold among the dross.)

Which is what you did by using those Venn diagrams, as was suggested.

Good work.

Answer (score 0):

You have used $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C)$, and in fact all data provided in the question to calculate $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ in part (a).
Your solutions for (c) and (d) then used $P(A\cup B\cup C)$.